# Spatial resolution and variable name for Microsoft building footprint data?

Tags: qgis, json

I am trying to work with the Microsoft building footprint data

https://github.com/microsoft/GlobalMLBuildingFootprints

They have collated all data here as json

https://minedbuildings.blob.core.windows.net/global-buildings/buildings-coverage.geojson

However, I am not able to determine what is the data itself.

Is it total building area in m2 or mean building area m2 in each polygon and spatial resolution of the data?

When reading the json, the data appears as polygons so it seems the irregular vector building shapefiles are now polygonised

[image]

EDIT 2:
In this link, I can see that they have combined the building footprint into a single dataset

https://github.com/microsoft/GlobalMLBuildingFootprints

If I scroll down to the page above, they provide a link to the combined file which is a json which opens this file which is in my original question.

https://minedbuildings.blob.core.windows.net/global-buildings/buildings-coverage.geojson

[image]
[image]

Comment: I apologize but I do not quite understand your question. Building footprint is a polygon that presents the area that is covered by a building when it is projected flat on the ground.

Comment: By reading the GitHub issue https://github.com/microsoft/GlobalMLBuildingFootprints/issues/13 you have downloaded a vector version of this index map https://github.com/microsoft/GlobalMLBuildingFootprints/blob/main/images/country-overview.png that shows where data are available. The real data can be downloaded from other links. For example US data from https://github.com/microsoft/USBuildingFootprints.

Comment: see the link: https://github.com/microsoft/GlobalMLBuildingFootprints/issues/65

Actually this is number of buildings per quad key